# Android library can not compile kotlin

Tags: android, rx-java, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions, kotlin-extension

My project has two projects: `main project` and `library project`.

The `main project` dependency `library project`.

Now I want to use `kotlin` both of them. I had added my `common rx extension code` into `library project`:

```
fun String.rxRequest(@NotNull builder: (Request.Builder) -> Unit): Observable<Response> = Observable.create<Response> {
  var mBuilder: Request.Builder = Request.Builder().url(this)
  builder.invoke(mBuilder);
  it.onNext(HttpClient.create().newCall(mBuilder.build()).execute())
  it.onCompleted()
}.subscribeOn(Schedulers.from(THREAD_POOL_NET));
```

And then I call this function in my `main project`:

```
"http://www.xxx.xxx".rxRequest {
        val requestBody = FormEncodingBuilder().add("code", code).build()
        it.post(requestBody)
                .header("XRDid", appInfo.deviceId)
    }
```

It build failed:

`LoginPresenter.kt: Unresolved reference: rxRequest`

`library project` build success, kotlin .class generated in build folder.

But `main project` build failed, have no kotlin .class file in build folder.

Comment: Did you import the rxRequest function in your main project?

Comment: @yole Yes, I import `rxRequest` function in my `main project`. When I move the `reRequest` function to my `main project`, it work.

Comment: Did the answer from @juancho help?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, **I fix it adding all the kotlin dependencies in both modules/projects** and of course make sure to add also the kotlin plugin and setting the kotlin folder to be included in the javaSrc.